# Can nodejs be installed on a free webhost

Tags: node.js

My goal is to create a chatting website. Not so much for the sake of the website, but for the experience so I know how; just something to work towards gradually. I tried long polling, but that always ends up pissing off the webhosts whose servers I'm using. I was told to use nodejs instead. I have some idea of what it is, but no idea how to use it.

I'm guessing that the reason I can't find the answer to this question anywhere is because of how obvious it is... to everyone else.

I've been looking around and all I see are tutorials on installing it on your server when you own the server. I know you can install forums on webhost's servers, so can you also install nodejs?

Comment: Not a silly question - node.js applications have very different requirements from the run-of-the-mill PHP sites that most webhosts are  designed to support.  Thus, node doesn't work very well, or at all, on sites like Go Daddy or Dreamhost.  You really want a service like the ones mentioned below that is designed to deal with long-running server processes, persistent HTTP connections, port-sharing, and other node-specific behaviors.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes. You can check the full listing at https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Node-Hosting to check each site but it does not categorize it by free hosting..
Some I know of, I personally use Heroku.

- [Heroku](http://www.heroku.com/)
- [Nodester](http://nodester.com/)

Comment: Sorry, I'm talking about online webhosts. I'm very confused at this point. Is Heroku an online webhosting service or something you download to run your own hosting for free?

Comment: Yes it is online, you don't run your own hosting with heroku. Also, you need to have ruby installed on your local. Here's two links that could maybe help you start, http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart and http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/windows for windows.

Comment: I would like to suggest also https://www.openshift.com/ that, from my experience, have a good support for Web Sockets. Currently, on Heroku, Web Socket-s are closed after 60s of inactivity.

Answer (score 7):

Most standard LAMP hosting companies don't let you run node.js.

I currently recommend you use the [Cloud9 IDE](http://cloud9ide.com) to get up and running with not only your tests and development, but also potential deployment. Cloud9 allows you to run your app from their IDE and will provide you with URL to see your app running and get familiar with node.js development.

A more manual way is to find a node.js PAAS (Platform as a Service) such as [Joyent](http://www.joyent.com/products/) or [Nodester](http://nodester.com/).

Comment: +1 for c9.io, written in Node, for writing in Node. Has worked nicely in my experience.

Answer (score 3):

Another one is [Open Shift](https://www.openshift.com/). I use them a lot and they allow you to use your own domain on the free plan. I use Heroku as well and have tried AppFog and Modulus.

But what it comes down to is whether I can use my own domain and how much they throttle my traffic. AppFog and Modulus don't allow custom domains on their free plans and seriously throttle traffic. They will cut your website off if you have one visitor an hour.

Another issue I was concerned about was with the upload of files. In particular, with my website content is added via markdown files. Most node webhosts use a variation on git deploys to update websites, with content supplied by databases. However, if you are trying to run a website without a database, using flat files, then each update must be done by a git deploy. This takes the whole website down and recreates a new website altogether (it just happens to look like the previous one). This will normally take a few minutes. Probably not a problem for a low volume website. But imagine if you are making a blog entry and you deploy it and then notice you've made a spelling mistake. You need to do a deploy all over again.

So, one of the things that attracted me to Open Shift was that they have a reserved area for flat files within your project. You can upload your files there and when your project is re-started these files will be preserved.

Answer (score 1):

[Appfog](http://appfog.com) provides a free plan where you can host NodeJS and many other technos.

However, free plans don't allow custom domain name anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There is also the [Node.js Smart Machine service](http://wiki.joyent.com/display/node/Node.js+SmartMachine+FAQ#Node.jsSmartMachineFAQ-HowdoIprovisionaNode.js%E2%84%A2SmartMachine) from Joyent.